# Extending pandas: astype changes DataFrame class type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When inheriting from pd.DataFrame it is not clear to me why astype() changes the result back to pd.DataFrame rather than the new type subclassing pd.DataFrame? Is there a `@property` I can define similar to `_constructor` to  make sure that `df.astype()` returns the correct type?

docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html

```
import pandas as pd

class DF(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return self.__class__


df = DF({
    'A': [1,2,3],
    'B': [10,20,30],
    'C': [100,200,300],
})  # Type is DF


a = df['A'] # type is Series
ab = df[['A', 'B']] # type is DF

dtypes = {'A': 'float64', 'B': 'float64', 'C': 'float64'}
x = df.astype(dtypes)

type(x)  # type is pd.DataFrame
```